# How to do numerical integration in python?

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I can't install anything new I need to use the default python library and I have to integrate a function. I can get the value for any f(x) and I need to integrate from 0 to 6 for my function f(x).

Comment: To avoid the question being closed without being answered, please refer to [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 11):

In discrete form, integration is just summation, i.e.

[image]

where n is the number of samples. If we let b-a/n be dx (the 'width' of our sample) then we can write this in python as such:

```
def integrate(f, a, b, dx=0.1):
    i = a
    s = 0
    while i <= b:
        s += f(i)*dx
        i += dx
    return s
```

Note that we make use of [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) here. Specifically, `f` is a function that is passed to `integrate`. `a`, `b` are our bounds and `dx` is 1/10 by default. This allows us to apply our new integration function to any function we wish, like so:

```
# the linear function, y = x
def linear(x):
    return x

integrate(linear, 1, 6) // output: 17.85

# or using lamdba function we can write it directly in the argument
# here is the quadratic function, y=x^2
integrate(lambda x: x**2, 0, 10) // output: 338.35
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (out of my zoo of packages):

```py
import numpy
import quadpy


def f(x):
    return numpy.sin(x) - x


val, err = quadpy.quad(f, 0.0, 6.0)
print(val)
```

```
-17.96017028290743
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def func():
    print "F(x) = 2x + 3"
    x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer value for x: '))
    Fx = 2 * x + 3
    return Fx

print func()
```

using the input function in python, you can randomly enter any number you want and get the function or if hard coding this this necessary you can use a for loop and append the numbers to a list for example

```
def func2():
    print "F(x) = 2x + 3"
    x = []
    for numbers in range(1,7):
        x.append(numbers)

    upd = 0
    for i in x:
        Fx = 2 * x[upd] + 3
        upd +=1
        print Fx

print func2()
```

**EDIT:** if you would like the numbers to start counting from 0 set the first value in range to 0 instead of 1

Comment: This evaluates the function, it doesn't do any integration.

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detail what you want?

Comment: You evaluated the function over the range [1,6]; the poster needs the integral over the range [0,6].  I don't see anywhere that you've dealt with the definite integral of a given function.  See the earlier answer for a good presentation.